# How to convert space separated data to csv format - Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to add a comma to the first two spaces in the string(File), and then I want to add a semicolon to the third instant. The problem I am trying to solve is; by using this RegX command `result = re.sub("\s", ",", text)` it returns `text="example,text,example,"`. This of course only replaces any spaces with a comma. How do I use regex to do the example below?

Example File

```
536924636   www.microsoft.com   http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/crl/MicW
536924733   www.microsoft.com   http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/certs/Mi
536925898   crl.microsoft.com   http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/product
536924636   www.microsoft.com   http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/crl/MicW
536924733   www.microsoft.com   http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/certs/Mi
536925898   crl.microsoft.com   http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/product
536924636   www.microsoft.com   http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/crl/MicW
536924733   www.microsoft.com   http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/certs/Mi
```

Edited;

```
536924636,www.microsoft.com,http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/crl/MicW;536924733,www.microsoft.com,http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/certs/Mi;536925898,crl.microsoft.com,http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/product(etc..);
```

In a nutshell, I am trying to use Regex and Python to read in text and turn it into a CSV format.

How do I achieve this ???

Thanks

Comment: Why does it have to be regex, though?

Comment: `"{};".format(";".join([x.replace(" ", ",") for x in text.splitlines()]))`? See [demo](https://ideone.com/feia6B).

Comment: @Aran-Fey Doesn’t have to be, have you got a better way of doing this ?

Comment: Is that supposed to be a multiline string? How did you feed it to the interpreter (in the current form)?

Comment: This is just an example, I have a text file which contains strings formatted in rows of 3.

Comment: Use `"{};".format(";".join([x.replace("\t", ",") for x in text.splitlines()]))`

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/jEP0xT code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text = """536924636   www.microsoft.com   http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/crl/MicW
536924733   www.microsoft.com   http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/certs/Mi
536925898   crl.microsoft.com   http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/product
536924636   www.microsoft.com   http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/crl/MicW
536924733   www.microsoft.com   http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/certs/Mi
536925898   crl.microsoft.com   http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/product
536924636   www.microsoft.com   http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/crl/MicW
536924733   www.microsoft.com   http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/certs/Mi
"""

print("%s;" % ";".join([line.strip().replace("\t", ",") for line in text.splitlines()]))
```

**Output**

```
536924636,www.microsoft.com,http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/crl/MicW;536924733,www.microsoft.com,http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/certs/Mi;536925898,crl.microsoft.com,http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/product;536924636,www.microsoft.com,http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/crl/MicW;536924733,www.microsoft.com,http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/certs/Mi;536925898,crl.microsoft.com,http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/product;536924636,www.microsoft.com,http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/crl/MicW;536924733,www.microsoft.com,http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/certs/Mi;
```

**Function: join()**

This function returns a string, which is the concatenation of the strings in the sequence passed - `'seperator'.join(sequence)`.

*Edit:*

**Reading from file**

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as file:
    print("%s;" % ";".join([line.strip().replace("\t", ",") for line in file.readlines()]))
```

Comment: This works for the example above but when I apply this to the text file I'm trying to read it dosnt work. It just adds a ';' att the end. I will update the example above.

Comment: meaning that you don't have lines; right? care to attach the payload in the question?

Comment: I have updated the example above; I hope this explains a tad clearer

Comment: Updated; check now.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't fully work for me, it is missing out the commas.
Example:
2176346692 crl.microsoft.com http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/product;2143060315 www.microsoft.com  http://www.microsoft.com/windows;

Comment: Change the seperator spaces depending on what you are using.

Comment: In the `replace()` function; the first parameter is the match, the second the value to replace it with. - So change the first parameter to the value that is being used between the values in the file.

Comment: I'm using a double whitespace in mine, (since your example in the question shows so) but in the comment it seems like you need to change it to single.

Comment: I have made that change but still no dice. Is there a good way I can share the file with you?

Comment: Sure we can always take this to a chat.

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/luuuzuw2b2d8gao/text.txt/file

I have uploaded the text file to here, would love to use the chat feature but i need 20 rep...

Comment: I want to add the ';' to declare the line separator.

Comment: Fair enough; the values are separated by a tab. - Meaning you'll need to pass a tab to the first replace parameter.

Comment: Adding "\t" worked!
 print("%s;" % ";".join([line.strip().replace("\t", ",") for line in file.readlines()]))

Comment: Thanks for staying with me @Julian Camilleri, we got there in the end :)

Comment: I am too! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`(?m)[^\S\r\n]+(?=(?:\S+[^\S\r\n]*)+$)`

I have illustrated the code at [this link](https://regex101.com/r/syfjAm/1).

Comment: This does successfully add commas to the first 2 spaces, would you be able to add a ";" to the last word in the file? This would solve my issue using RegX

Comment: @Ac3 if you have read the whole text into a single string, you may use `re.sub(r'(?m)(?=([^\S\r\n]+))\1(?!$)|[\r\n]+', lambda x: "," if x.group(1) else ";", text)`